# zlib Inflate returning -3 while decompressing .bmp image file in c++

Tags: c++, zlib

- [Inflate (decompress) PNG file using ZLIB library C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524709/inflate-decompress-png-file-using-zlib-library-c)

I tried with the above reference still failing.

`imgdata` is of type `char *` means (`char*` imgdata)

```
 string strnew = imgdata;
                DecompressBuffer(imgdata,compressedlength,strnew);
```

DecompressBuffer function is defined in the above reference link. Can someone helps why inflate failing?

Comment: The title says that you want to compress, but your code decompresses. Are you sure that `imgdata` is a valid zlib-deflated stream? And what do you hope to achieve by initializing `strnew` to `imgdata`?

Comment: Yes I want to decompress the data .In my application i will get the char *  buffer but in the above function we have to  pass string that is why i converted char*  buffer in to string and passed to    this function DecompressBuffer(imgdata,compressedlength,strnew)..Actually i will get decompress data as  string again i will convert that data to char * buffer before settting it to  clipboard. Please help me to decompress the the data

Comment: But `strnew` is the output, not the input. Why are you initializing the output to the input? It's not the source of the problem, but it's also just not right.